# How to display all the duplicate results while i compare with a set of results from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all the students who belong to Term A and are part of a different groups from student registration table and compare those results and check if they have registered for any other terms other than Term A and if they have a similar groups. If they have different groups then i need to display the result form Term A and results of term other than A

```
> SELECT sra.studentid,sra.StudentName,sra.Term,sra.Group
 FROM StudentReg sra
join (select * from 
(SELECT sra1.studentid,sra1.StudentName,sra1.Term,sra1.Group
FROM StudentReg sra1
)mq where mq.Term <> 'A'
)sra1 on sra.StudentID=sra1.StudentID       
where sra.Term='A'
```

This displays only the results who have registered for the same group in Term A. but i need to display both of them, the one from term A and the one with the same group in terms other than A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only fields from table sra in your first select, that is applicable for the output. So put your list of fields from sra1 to this select, too:

```
SELECT sra.studentid,sra.StudentName,sra.Term,sra.Group,
sra1.studentid,sra1.StudentName,sra1.Term,sra1.Group
 FROM StudentReg sra
join (select * from 
(SELECT sra1.studentid,sra1.StudentName,sra1.Term,sra1.Group
FROM StudentReg sra1
)mq where mq.Term <> 'A'
)sra1 on sra.StudentID=sra1.StudentID       
where sra.Term='A'
```

This should result in output of data to term A and term other than A.

Your statement could be more simple like this:

```
SELECT sra.studentid,sra.StudentName,sra.Term,sra.Group, 
  sra1.studentid,sra1.StudentName,sra1.Term,sra1.Group
  FROM StudentReg sra
  JOIN StudentReg sra1 on sra.StudentID=sra1.StudentID       
WHERE sra.Term='A' and sra1.Term <> 'A'
```

I don't see a need for the subselects.